# asp.net backspace key press repeat previous postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .NET and can use some help. I have been working on a VB6 database client side frontend with mySql backend for years. Now I am moving to .NET 4.0 Web server side frontend with C#.

I just started on my first data entry page. I have a listbox for a Sql dataset from db. User click an item in the list to load the record tags into bunch of textboxes, ddls, gridview, and table for editing. Most things worked so far as I wanted, but I just found a weird thing. After loading a record from the list, I double clicked a textbox which is set to read-only and disabled, the content is highlighted, then I hit the backspace key (by accident actually), the previous postback action was performed (which is to load the records into the listbox and clear all controls for record tages).

How do I prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a browser-based feature (mapping backspace to "back"). You could try and capture the keyboard event and prevent it from bubbling up, since I think that only happens if the webpage doesn't eat that keyboard event.

Comment: Thanks for the help, abluejelly.